# Zookeeper: fails to load a main class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, ubuntu-16.04

I'm starting to work with ubuntu  and Apache kafka and have the following problem when I run **bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties&**

**:~/Documentos/kafka-0.8.2.1-src$ Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain**

kafka:kafka-0.8.2.1
ubuntu:16.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your Kafka download. You have downloaded `kafka-0.8.2.1-src` source package which just contains Kafka source code and external(like zookeeper) classes declarations and doesn't come with external classes bundled with it.

The solution is you need to download `binary package` which looks like `kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.tgz` and this contains all classes bundled within it.

**Note:** In case if you want to use `source package` then you have to compile it on your system before installation.